Run jobs conditionally in GitHub Actions
I'm trying to control a list of services to deploy on GitHub Actions with checkboxes in workflow_dispatch:
  workflow_dispatch:
   inputs:
      graphics:
        type: boolean
        required: false
        default: false
      tags:
        description: 'trigger manually'
        
  push:
    branches:
      - "release"

jobs:  
  graphics:
    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.graphics == true || github.event.inputs.graphics == false }}
    name: call graphicstransform deploy
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deploygraphics.yml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      external: 'true'

I'm checking for either true or false with github.event.inputs.graphics but the graphics job is never executed.
Why not? How can I run jobs conditionally in workflow_dispatch with checkbox booleans?

"The workflow will also receive the inputs in the github.event.inputs context. The information in the inputs context and github.event.inputs context is identical except that the inputs context preserves Boolean values as Booleans instead of converting them to strings." So you either need github.event.inputs.graphics == "true" or inputs.graphics == true.

You have a typo in your inputs definition; According to the validation schema;
One MUST specify whether input is required or not, and if it is not required, one MUST provide a default value.
    inputs:
      graphics:
        type: boolean
        required: true
      tags:
        type: string
        default: my_tag
        required: false
        description: "trigger manually"

You also may access the input directly as shown in the example
if: ${{ inputs.graphics == true }}

Or like this
if: ${{ github.event.inputs.graphics == "true" }}


ok fixed according to scheme

If you run this workflow, you will see that inputs.graphics and github.event.inputs.graphics are typed differently. You can see below how to use both:
name: boolean-input

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      graphics:
        type: boolean

jobs:
  graphics:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Show github context
        run: echo '${{ toJson(github.event.inputs) }}'
      - name: Show inputs context
        run: echo '${{ toJson(inputs) }}'
      - name: call graphicstransform deploy via inputs.graphics
        if: inputs.graphics
        run: echo graphics
      - name: call graphicstransform deploy via github.event.inputs.graphics
        if: github.event.inputs.graphics == 'true'
        run: echo graphics

